# Simple RSS feed manipulation software

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

I like the functionality of [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/), but don't want to leave the task of processing RSS feeds to a privately owned web service which might disappear tomorrow and I don't exactly trust my data with. I'd like to do this with software I can run locally (on a server or desktop; doesn't matter).

There must be something out there that handles some of the basic functionality of Pipes such as merging feeds, filtering, querying for keywords, etc. but I'm having a hard time finding it. There are various parsers that *might* do the job, but they're overly flexible and require much configuration upfront. Ideally I'd have something in the lines of a simple command that I can run in a cron job, or a daemon, which will fetch some feeds, perform the operations I want, and output or serve the resulting RSS feed. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I think you will find that feed manipulation sofware is, almost by definition, far from simple ;)

Comment: I have the same feeling. Maybe if Murat go back and edit their Ask, we can redo our Answer to best fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my currently rather limited real use scenarios, I ended up using [Planet Venus](https://github.com/rubys/venus). There seems to be no general purpose tool in the lines of what I described, so I'll probably make my own.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is particularly helpful, but I've written a little script to scrape together a bunch of feeds into an html document. This has been running on my computers every hour for years now. I've written it when I just started using Python. But it works.

Even though it's quite late in the day, I've somehow managed to put together a README document, it should be very straightforward to use now.

[Download (15,4 KB)](http://www-stud.uni-due.de/~sfstpala/frss.tar.bz2)

It works nicely on Ubuntu 10.10, but it may require that you install `python-feedparser` (which is actually doing all the work).

I hope it's of some use.

Comment: Thanks; it's not useful for this purpose but I may need it in the future. Let me know if you've made other things using feedparser; I may end up writing my own thing with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/151888/rss-feed-reader-from-the-terminal-in-linux). My recoomendation is [newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/) feed reader: Simple and fast. Easy to install:

```
  $ sudo aptitude install newsbeuter
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a feed reader; I'm looking for a simple way to do things like sort, merge and filter feeds.

Comment: In this case, you are looking for Universal Feed Parser (http://www.feedparser.org). Its a python lib (all in one file) very easy to use. Very good choice for a prototype project and also recommended for production too.

Comment: I know about it, as you'll note in my comment to Stefano's answer.

Comment: @Murat: Your 'Ask' is really difficult to answer. Looks like you are not looking for a library where you can starting some code with, and also you are no looking for a feed reader in the sense of a desktop application. You should give us more clues to help answer you instead of downgrade us.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear. If there's something particular you find vague, please ask for it to be clarified in a comment to the original question.

Comment: newsbeuter... love it... nice and simple and does what I want. Thanks (+) for the recomendation

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Liferea.  Seems the most commonly used rss feeder application in Ubuntu and it GTK.

```
sudo apt-get install liferea
```

Comment: I don't think Murat is looking for a reader

Comment: Good answer, wrong question... I found this question because I was looking for an RSS reader .. I'm using the Terminal more these days, so I'll go for  crncosta's suggestion, but I am tempted by liferea.. It is nice and simple, and that's what I want.. (+)